# Cocos2d crash at [CCDirector setNextScene]

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am having difficulty resolving a crash when changing scenes.  This is the dealloc method of the scene being replaced.  It is being called and I know that there is no memory leak or heap bloat.  Can anyone suggest what possible stupid/obvious mistake(s) I might be making.  I apologize for the idiocy.

```
-(void) dealloc
{
NSLog(@"Dungeon.m dealloc called");

[self removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:true];
[self unscheduleAllSelectors];
[[CCScheduler sharedScheduler]unscheduleAllSelectors];

if (entityList) [entityList release];
if (lopsidedList) [lopsidedList release];
if (monsterNames) [monsterNames release];
if (menuSprites) [menuSprites release];
if (menuLabels) [menuLabels release];
if (monsterLevels) [monsterLevels release];
if (theMagicFactory) [theMagicFactory release];
if (theDM) [theDM release];
if (theDisplay) [theDisplay release];
if (aDungeonLevel) [aDungeonLevel release];
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Player Retain Count: %i",[thePlayer retainCount]]);

[super dealloc]
}
```

I have confirmed that deallocs for the significant listed objects are called:

```
2012-09-09 10:51:31.840 Pocket Dungeons[947:707] Dungeon.m dealloc called
2012-09-09 10:51:31.878 Pocket Dungeons[947:707] DungeonMaster.m dealloc called.
2012-09-09 10:51:31.910 Pocket Dungeons[947:707] DungeonDisplay.m dealloc called
2012-09-09 10:51:31.915 Pocket Dungeons[947:707] dungeonlevel.m dealloccalled
```

This is the changing scene code:

```
            else if (whatIsHere==STAIRS_UP) {
                if (thePlayer.currentDungeonLevel==1) {
                    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Self Retain Count: %i",[self retainCount]]);
                    thePlayer.theDungeon = nil;
                    theDM.theDungeon = nil;
                    theDisplay.theDungeon = nil;

                    for (int i=0; i<[aDungeonLevel.mArray count]; i++) {
                        Monster *aMonster = [aDungeonLevel.mArray objectAtIndex:i];
                        aMonster.theDungeon = nil;
                    }


                    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Self Retain Count: %i",[self retainCount]]);
//                    CCScene *aScene = [Town nodeWithPlayer:thePlayer];
                    CCScene *aScene = [CharacterMaker2 nodeWithPlayer:thePlayer];
                    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:aScene];
```

This is where the crash occurs:

```
0   0x34311f78 in objc_msgSend ()

1   0x000fef28 in -[CCDirector setNextScene] at /Users/nehrujuman212/Documents/Pocket Dungeons/Pocket Dungeons/libs/cocos2d/CCDirector.m:429

2   0x0014ab44 in -[CCDirectorIOS drawScene] at /Users/nehrujuman212/Documents/Pocket Dungeons/Pocket Dungeons/libs/cocos2d/Platforms/iOS/CCDirectorIOS.m:160

3   0x0014c858 in -[CCDirectorDisplayLink mainLoop:] at /Users/nehrujuman212/Documents/Pocket Dungeons/Pocket Dungeons/libs/cocos2d/Platforms/iOS/CCDirectorIOS.m:721

4   0x33fd386e in CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch(unsigned long long, unsigned long long) ()

5   0x33fd37c4 in CA::Display::IOMFBDisplayLink::callback(__IOMobileFramebuffer*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, void*) ()

6   0x37387000 in IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc ()

7   0x31bf060c in IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage ()

8   0x3228af12 in __CFMachPortPerform ()

9   0x32295522 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()

10  0x322954c4 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()

11  0x32294312 in __CFRunLoopRun ()

12  0x322174a4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()

13  0x3221736c in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()

14  0x3136e438 in GSEventRunModal ()

15  0x31d16cd4 in UIApplicationMain ()

16  0x0016ea1e in main at /Users/nehrujuman212/Documents/Pocket Dungeons/Pocket Dungeons/main.m:14
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your changing scenes code? `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:...]` ?

Comment: Hmm.. I am suspecting that `[CharacterMaker2 nodeWithPlayer:thePlayer];` is the problem. Are you sure `CharacterMaker2` is a subclass of `CCScene` ? I wouldn't mind looking at your whole project if you can upload it somewhere.

Comment: I'd rather not upload my project. I don't think charactermaker2 is the problem.  I have partially been able to avoid the crash by allowing the retain count of dungeon to be greater than 0 by not setting to nil in another class, so the problem was related to it being deleted before cocos2d was finished with it, I think.  Unfortunately, doing so is causing strange behavior: animation seems to stop working (eg. charactermaker2, where a previous instance had normally working animation, this new instance does not).  Seems like magic to me (Oops! I broke Cocos2d) - any ideas?

Comment: Damn, memory problems are tough. I honestly can't help you with memory issues without the full project.. (Use an ARC template. It will conserve some of your hair from being pulled out)... In any case, have you overriden `onEnter:`? are you sure you are calling `super onEnter:` inside? and for the sake of completeness, repeat with `onExit:`.

Comment: Thanks.  From the cocos2d reference for [[CCScheduler sharedScheduler]unscheduleAllSelectors]: "You should NEVER call this method, unless you know what you are doing."  I don't.  So, I commented it out and everything works now.  Still coming to peace with the retains and releases, but at least I can keep coding.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, I can adequately answer my own question, though the answer could use some further input.

I think the problem was that cocos2d was releasing the "running scene" from CCDirector:setNextScene, after I had allowed it to be deallocated.  By carefully checking my releases and retains, I was able to allow it to be retained a bit longer to allow cocos2d time to do its housekeeping.

I was overzealously trying to not retain my object anywhere, ergo I used CCScheduler UnscheduleAllSelectors, which is a no-no for run-of-the-mill guys like me.  The take home for me is: be careful not to screw up your code when you're trying to correct it; and be patient: logic is logical.  Also, I learned to access the cocos2d source code to help me and also gained better skill at using the instruments, especially examination of the heap.

Comment: `retainCount` is useless; don't call it.  Manual retain-release is pretty easy and easy to screw up;  if you want an object to stick around, you retain it.  If you +new/+alloc/-retain/-copy, you must -release for it to be deallocated.  You *never* try to balance the retain count of an object with -release calls;  down that path lies assured failure.

Comment: @bbum: Yes, but retainCount is, I think, useful, because it helps you investigate why an object is not being released. +new/+alloc, etc . . . -release are only a small subset of the things that will retain an object.  Relying on that alone is woefully inadequate.  For example, using retain count, I noticed that the number was proportional with the number of monster objects I had, thus alerting me to set the properties of those objects to nil, since the default setter methods also retain pointers they are given.

Comment: No, the `retainCount` is not useful for that.   `retainCount` never reflects `autorelease` state nor does it reflect thread state.   There are far, far, better tools.   http://whentouseretaincount.com/